# $_POST and INSERT INTO Convert in PDO

Tags: php, sql, insert, pdo

hy friends I have a problem, I've created an script without pdo and is sqli vulnerable, sql connection is pdo because is simple to do that but in this case situation is changed. Please help me, this is the code:

```
<?php require ("../SQL.php");

#######De aici am setat creearea directoarelor pentru poze#####
$model          = "$_POST[model]";
$marca          = "$_POST[marca]";

 mkdir ("\\server\\htdocs\\panou\\poze\\{$marca}/{$model}", 0777, true);
$director_poza = ("poze/{$marca}/{$model}/");    
$numetmp_poza  = $_FILES['numepoza1']['name'];
$numepoza1     = $director_poza.$numetmp_poza;
$numetmp_poza  = $_FILES['numepoza2']['name'];
$numepoza2     = $director_poza.$numetmp_poza;
$numetmp_poza  = $_FILES['numepoza3']['name'];
$numepoza3     = $director_poza.$numetmp_poza;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['numepoza1']['tmp_name'], $numepoza1))
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['numepoza2']['tmp_name'], $numepoza2))
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['numepoza3']['tmp_name'], $numepoza3))
{
list($width,$height,$type,$attr)= getimagesize($numepoza1);
switch($type)
{
case 1:
$ext = ".gif"; break;
case 2:
$ext = ".jpg"; break;
case 3:
$ext = ".png"; break;
default:
echo "Format foto neacceptat";
}

$insertie = "INSERT INTO modele 
(id, marca, model, utilizator, despre, data, data_luna, data_zi, img1, img2, img3,    doi_g, trei_g, patru_g, info_ecran, rezolutie_ecran, multitouch_ecran, protectie_ecran,  sunet_sonerii, sunet_mainilibere, sunet_mufa_jack, memorie_card, mcard_tip,  mcard_capacitate, intern_memorie, date_gprs, date_edge, date_viteze, date_wifi, date_bt,  date_nfc, date_usb, camera_spate, camera_fata, camera_tehnologii, camera_video, performanta_os, performanta_chipset, performanta_cpu, performanta_cpu_core, performanta_cpu_tip, performanta_rami, performanta_gpu, performanta_senzori, performanta_gps, performanta_java, altele_radio, altele_mesajerie, altele_filme, baterie_autonomie, baterie_mAh, baterie_convorbire, SEO_cuvinte_cheie)
VALUES
('',
'$_POST[marca]',
'$_POST[model]',
'$utilizator',
'$_POST[despre]',
'$_POST[data]',
'$_POST[data_luna]',
'$_POST[data_zi]',
'$numepoza1',
'$numepoza2',
'$numepoza3',
'$_POST[doi_g]',
'$_POST[trei_g]',
'$_POST[patru_g]',
'$_POST[info_ecran]',
'$_POST[rezolutie_ecran]',
'$_POST[multitouch_ecran]',
'$_POST[protectie_ecran]',
'$_POST[sunet_sonerii]',
'$_POST[sunet_mainilibere]',
'$_POST[sunet_mufa_jack]',
'$_POST[memorie_card]',
'$_POST[mcard_tip]',
'$_POST[mcard_capacitate]',
'$_POST[intern_memorie]',
'$_POST[date_gprs]',
'$_POST[date_edge]',
'$_POST[date_viteze]',
'$_POST[date_wifi]',
'$_POST[date_bt]',
'$_POST[date_nfc]',
'$_POST[date_usb]',
'$_POST[camera_spate]',
'$_POST[camera_fata]',
'$_POST[camera_tehnologii]',
'$_POST[camera_video]',
'$_POST[performanta_os]',
'$_POST[performanta_chipset]',
'$_POST[performanta_cpu]',
'$_POST[performanta_cpu_core]',
'$_POST[performanta_cpu_tip]',
'$_POST[performanta_rami]',
'$_POST[performanta_gpu]',
'$_POST[performanta_senzori]',
'$_POST[performanta_gps]',
'$_POST[performanta_java]',
'$_POST[altele_radio]',
'$_POST[altele_mesajerie]',
'$_POST[altele_filme]',
'$_POST[baterie_autonomie]',
'$_POST[baterie_mAh]',
'$_POST[baterie_convorbire]',
'$_POST[SEO_cuvinte_cheie]')"; 
$insertieresults = mysql_query($insertie) or die(mysql_error());
}
echo '<center>Succesuful!</center>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=adauga-tableta-tel.php"/>'; 
?>
```

I know that this is cleary vulnerable to hack-injects, thankyou in advance.

Comment: Not only is it clearly vulnerable to hack-injects, it's deprecated. Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: All working fine but I wanna convert this in PDO code

Comment: Could you clarify what the actual _question_ is?

Comment: Help me to convert this code in PDO code this is what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO isn't going to re-write your code for you. Look into using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and try it yourself first. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) post also seems relevant. If you have issues while you're writing is, come back and post your code. Then we can help.

Comment: ok thankyou Sean I will come back after some tryes